# UNMET Peer Dependency: platform-browser-dynamic@4.3.5 wants @angular/compiler@4.3.5

Tags: angular, npm

`UNMET Peer Dependency: platform-browser-dynamic@4.3.5 wants @angular/compiler@4.3.5`

But I installed explicitly beforehand the 4.3.5 compiler with save switch. What is this?

Comment: run `npm list --depth=0` and show the output

Answer (score 0):

Solved everything:

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo npm install npm -g
```